# Read from firebase database and store the data, return values to be used in other pages

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I first try to get the data from firebase, then call a function to update the outer variable (setdata). The function however creates a local variable and doesnt update the outer one.

I was wondering how I can update the outer variable?

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

function userData() {  
  var userInfo 

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      getUserData(user.uid)
    }
  })

  function getUserData(uid) {
    firebase
     .database()
     .ref('users/' + uid)
     .once("value")
     .then(function (snapshot){
        setData(snapshot.val())
      })
  }

  function setData(data){
    userInfo.name = data.name;
    userInfo.username = data.username;
  }

  return({ nameOf: userInfo.name, usernameOf: userInfo.username});
}

export default userInformation = {
  name: userData().nameOf,
  username: userData.usernameOf,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the following and got results,

`````
var usr = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var usrId = usr.uid;
var ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + usrId)

var latestSnapshot = null;
ref.on('value', function(snap) { latestSnapshot = snap.val(); });

export default latestSnapshot````
`````

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the way you handled it. Please try this way and let me know if it worked. It should work...

`userData.js`

```
export default function userData() {
  return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      return getUserData(user.uid);
    }
  });

  function getUserData(uid) {
    return firebase
      .database()
      .ref('users/' + uid)
      .once('value')
      .then(function (snapshot) {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        return { name: data.name, username: data.username };
      });
  }
}
```

When you want to use the above function,

```
import userData from 'path/to/userData/js';

const userInformation = userData();
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that the return value instead of being an object is the following: 'firebase.Unsubscribe'

Comment: I think I've done a mistake. I've updated the code. Please check...

Comment: doing above again i get the same result: 'const userInformation: firebase.Unsubscribe'